# Cannot access admin site in django with custom user

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-admin, django-authentication

I have a problem with django, I cannot login to admin site, the app just stops when I try to login to admin but everything is fine if I try to login user to site, just cant access admin. I've read all articles about it on the stackoverflow, I tried different AUTH_BACKENDS and none of them works. I'm really desperate
So, this is my settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'users.apps.UsersConfig',

]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'untitled.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
        ,
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'untitled.wsgi.application'


DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'mentor',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': 'localhost',  # Or an IP Address that your DB is hosted on
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}


AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "users.CustomUser"
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (

    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.RemoteUserBackend'

)
```

this is my custom user model:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    STUDENT = 'STUDENT'  
    MENTOR = 'MENTOR'  
    REDOVNI = 'REDOVNI'
    IZVANREDNI = 'IZVANREDNI'

    ROLE_CHOICES = [
        (STUDENT, 'student'),  
        (MENTOR, 'mentor'), ] 
    STATUS_CHOICES = [
        (REDOVNI, 'redovni'),
        (IZVANREDNI, 'izvanredni')]

    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default=REDOVNI)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=ROLE_CHOICES, default=STUDENT)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

my managers.py

```
class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    """
    Custom user model manager where email is the unique identifiers
    for authentication instead of usernames.
    """
    ROLE = (
        ('s', 'student'),
        ('m', 'mentor'),
    )

    STATUS = (
        ('red', 'redovni'),
        ('izv', 'izvanredni'),
    )



    def create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):

        if not email:
            raise ValueError(_('The Email must be set'))
        email = self.normalize_email(email)

        user = self.model(email=email, password=password, **extra_fields, )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user


    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):

        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError(_('Superuser must have is_staff=True.'))
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError(_('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.'))
        return self.create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)
```

and finally admin.py

```
class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    add_form = CustomUserCreationForm
    form = CustomUserChangeForm
    model = CustomUser
    list_display = ['email', 'username', ]
    ordering = ('email',)


admin.site.register(CustomUser, CustomUserAdmin)
```

Any help is welcome.

I

Comment: " app just stops when I try to login to admin", if you are using django 3, then it is an issue with django3. Try to downgrade it to v2.2 then check

Comment: in command line I get 302 and then it stops